# Is it appropriate to call actions frequently from a controller in Ember?

Tags: ember.js

From what I understand actions are meant to be used in templates to handle user events. However, in some Ember projects I sometimes see heavy use of the `send` function in controllers and other places that it doesn't feel like it belongs.

At first this doesn't seem like an idiomatic use of actions. Then why have the `send` function at all? If actions were only ever meant for user events they would only ever be accessible from templates. Everything else would make explicit function calls.

In short, is there some convention for using actions from controllers? A rule of thumb?

Answer (score 2):

Calling actions from wherever is an acceptable pattern.  Although if you are calling an action from within the controller's scope it might prove useful to move that code from the action into a separate function and have the action call that code.  Calling the action is still perfectly fine though.  You should remember, they are mostly a one way street. They work well for event driven problems, which often are UI interactions, but can be other things.

```
...
  someFunc: function(){
    this.doSomethingImpl(a,b);
  },
  doSomethingImpl: function(a,b){
    ...
  },
  actions: {
    doSomething: function(a,b){
      this.doSomethingImpl(a,b);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong in using `send` and sending actions inside the controller. However, it might be better to use explicit functions instead - matter of taste.

On the other hand, if you see a lot of `send` in couple of controllers and/or routes, it might be a good sign to check the parent routes of that controllers. Due to fact that the there is a rising convention `Data Down, Actions Up`, the flow between components and controllers should be ruled by sending data via one-way bindings down, but modify them only on the data-owner level by receiving actions to perform change.

A lot of `send` occurences may mean that the convention is introduced in that project and controllers with parent routes and controllers are communicating via sending actions.

There is a very interesting, although quite long, RFC about [The Road to Ember 2.0](https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/pull/15), from where you can read more about the concepts and conventions that are going to appear.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a convention in the form of 'Data down, actions up'. Basically, in Ember 2.0 views and controllers are going away and will be replaced with components and a simplified, unidirectional data flow.

You can Google more about this but in the mean-time here are a couple of resources I've found valuable when I was trying to get my head around all of this:

http://burstcreations.com/blog/data-down-actions-up/
http://coryforsyth.com/2014/09/24/communicating-with-ember-js-components-using-sendaction/